# m3u8 http live streaming on motorola xoom tablet browser

Tags: android, html, video, android-3.0-honeycomb, xoom

I have a website that is streaming live video using m3u8. It works on the iOS devices and safari mac, but i also need it to work on the motorola honeycomb xoom tablet version 3.1 .

Here's my sample test code; m4v files work on the xoom, not m3u8

```
<video id='video' autobuffer height='240' src='http://testfile.m3u8'  width='360' controls></video>
<script>
  $("#video").play();
</script>
```

From googling around,

http://www.wowzamedia.com/forums/showthread.php?7532-HTML5-Support-for-video-playback
it appears that I can ONLY play m3u8 files in embedded video tag on Safari mac or IOS devices. If this is true, is there an alternative to getting m3u8 http live streaming working in a motorola xoom browser - perhaps an alternative media player that I can embed into a browser that does this? Better suggestions/recommendations.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post; first post missed this:"<video id='video' autobuffer height='240' src='BigBuck.m3u8'  width='360' controls></video> " right before the play();

Comment: Did you find an answer for this

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
http://testfile.m3u8
```

to

```
httplive://testfile.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 3.0 should support m3u8 HLS, are you encoding to H.264 **baseline profile**?

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html